# How to upload millions of rows of data from dbf file to SQL Server after removing special characters from the data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

My task is to upload a `.dbf` file to SQL Server after removing special characters which are present in the records.

I have used regular expression for removing special character. First data is loaded into data reader then loaded in data table.

After some manipulation in data again data is loaded into data table and then using bulk copy insert data is loaded into database.

It is working fine for 150000 rows, but for 3 million rows, I get an `OutOfMemoryException` while data is loaded into a datatable.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //Logic to Remove Special Characters from the file.
        dt.Load(dr); //OutOfMemoryException occurred here

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
                    row[i] = Regex.Replace(row[i].ToString(), "[#$%^*@!~?]", "");
            }
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
             // code for bulk insert
             bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i suggest you to use SSIS for this . It is very fast and easy to use

Comment: And web users up-loading a file are going to do this how? Now you can Shell() SSIS, but then again, that assumes the web hosting has SSIS available (that's not a given). And I don't believe that SSIS has the ability to clean out funny characters - does it?  So you missed this boat leaving the harbor on two counts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, You are reading all of the rows at once, which will obviously cause problems such as `OutOfMemoryException`.

What you would want to do is, DO NOT load all the data from `OleDbDataReader` to the `DataTable` object at once.

Here is my proposed solution as I see, you want to bulk insert the rows:

- After calling the `ExecuteReader()` method, get the schema of the
  table.
- Get Current Table schema and add the columns into your `DataTable` object. *(This `DataTable` object will be used to post the rows in bulk to SQL)*
- Read through the `OleDbDataReader` row by row and copy those rows to the `DataTable` where you copied the schema. *(`dr.Read()` method will read the data row by row)*.
- Check when rows count exceeds 1000 or if there are no further rows, submit those records that you have on hand to your SQL using `BulkCopy` then clear the table. *(You can increase this number according to the health of your memory)*
- Repeat until there are no further rows.

Here is your code re-written in my suggested way:

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var schemaTable = dr.GetSchemaTable(); // Get Metadata of the current table.
    var dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows) // Copy the schema to your datatable object
    {
        string colName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
        System.Type t = row.Field<System.Type>("DataType");
        dt.Columns.Add(colName, t);
    }
    bool hasNextRow = false;
    do
    {
        if (!hasNextRow) 
        {
            // We have to do this in order to peek through the next row. If we do not have next row, then we will have to commit the current changes
            hasNextRow = dr.Read();
        }
        if(!hasNextRow) break; // Break if there is no row.
        var newRow = dt.NewRow(); 
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) // Copy current row
        {
            newRow[col.ColumnName] = dr[col.ColumnName];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        hasNextRow = dr.Read();
        if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1000 || !hasNextRow) // When the data exceeds thousands rows Or when there are no further rows, insert the data into sql and clear the memory. 
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Adjust the values
            {
                 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                 {
                     if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
                         row[i] = Regex.Replace(row[i].ToString(), "[#$%^*@!~?]", "");
                 }
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                // code for bulk insert
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }

            dt.Rows.Clear(); // Clear the memory so new rows can be read.
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
    } while(hasNextRow);
}
```

**PS:** The code is not tested, so it might need some love.